# C - Program segfaulting when scanf() is called

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm learning C right now, and I copied this little snippet straight from the book I'm using. It segfaults when I run it and I can't figure out why, I ran it through gdb and it stops at line 9 scanf("%s", aName);, but printing the values of the variables brings up nothing suspicious looking. What's wrong with this thing?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int nameLength(char[]);

main () {
  char aName[20] = {'\0'};

  printf("\nEnter your first name: ");
  scanf('%s', aName);
  printf("\nYour first name contains %d letters.", nameLength(aName));
}

int nameLength(char name[]) {
  int result = 0;
  while (name[result] != '\0') {
    result++;
  }
  return result;
}
```

edit: I forgot to mention, it didn't even display the prompt or let me enter a name. it crashed immediately after executing it.

Comment: How about using the standard strlen function instead of nameLenght? How long was the name you entered?

Comment: You got your answer, but consider using some other book.  `scanf` isn't a safe function to use in this case, and a book that has the above code can't be very good.

Comment: Using fgets is safer that using scanf. Also you should be checking your return code to see if the scanf returned successfully or not.

Comment: Can you recommend another book?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the listing, you have `'%s'` instead of `"%s"` - note the diff between single and double quotes.  Single quotes delimit characters, double quotes delimit strings.  `scanf()` takes a string first argument, so you need double quotes.

Comment: You should turn on full warnings in whatever compiler you are using (eg -Wall for gcc).  It will bring you much in the form of enlightenment.  That would have caught this bug, and likely have told you exactly what was wrong.

Answer (score 4):

```
scanf('%s', aName);
```

Use double quotes:

```
scanf("%s", aName);
```

Or to be sure:

```
scanf("%19s", aName);
```

To limit the string to 19 characters

Answer (score 3):

Try replacing the scanf line with this:

```
scanf ("%s", aName);
```

Note the double quote.

...richie

Answer (score 2):

use double quotes in scanf

Answer (score 1):

If this is an exercise to count the number of letters then you could do the following, but using pointers.

```
int nameLength(char *name)
{
    int i = 0;
    while(*name++) {
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}
```